# jerking effect animating moving object

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a box which constantly moves left to right in a given range. I also have left and right control for the moving box. My problem is this, how can i make the animation smoother. At the moment, when it is animating towards the right for instance, and you click the left control, it becomes jerky or jumps. I have created a jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfb5A/)

```
$(".nav .left").click(function(){
            $("#boss").animate({
                left: "-=50"
            });     
            return false;
        });


        $(".nav .right").click(function(){
            $("#boss").animate({
                left: "+=50"
            });     
            return false;
        });



        function animateBoss() {
            var top   = randomMinMax(0 , 0);
            var left  = randomMinMax(0   , 400);    
            var speed = randomMinMax(1000, 1000);


            boss.animate({ top: top, left: left }, {
                duration: speed,
                queue   : false,
                complete: animateBoss
            });
        }    `enter code here`


        animateBoss();
```

Comment: Why don't you just queue them? This way the new animation will wait for the current one before it starts and the transition between the animations will be smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "jerky" movement is caused by two conflicting animations: that triggered by `animateBoss()` and that triggered by clicking "left" or "right".

I had success by stopping animations prior to manual "left"/"right" movement and restarting `animateBoss()` when such movements are complete:

I'm using jQuery's [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop animations:

Syntax: `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

```
$(".nav .right").click(function(){
    $("#boss").stop(true,false).animate({
        left: "+=50"
    },function() {
        animateBoss();
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfb5A/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery animate you should prefix your animations with `dequeue()` and `stop()` if you are running more than 1 animation or repeating the same animation otherwise they may build up behind each other waiting to run and result in unintended delay.

```
$("#boss").dequeue().stop().animate({ left: "-=50" });
```

[Here's a full Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/dcdev/full/ByjjMv/)